# Is it possible to create a timer in jscript that you can manually change without it being affected by timezones?

Tags: java, javascript, timer, countdown

is it possible to create a timer where I can manually set the hours each day to a set number of hours but still remains accurate? For example; if I set the countdown for 5 hours at 2pm I want the timer to stop as soon as it hits 7pm. Also, when I set the timer for 5 hours I would like everyone in the world to see it countdown from 5 hours, no matter what the time is in their country. In the format: days hours minutes seconds.

The reason I want to do this is for a streamer's website. He needs a flexible timer which can be manually changed and is the same worldwide for his viewers to know when he starts streaming.

The current timer we're using at the moment;

```
setInterval(function(){
    var currentTime = new Date();

    if(currentTime.getHours() > 19){
        var countdownHours = (24 - currentTime.getHours()) + 19;
    }else if(currentTime.getHours() < 19){
        var countdownHours = 19 - currentTime.getHours();
    }else{
        var countdownHours = 0;
    }

    var countdownMins = 59 - currentTime.getMinutes();
    var countdownSecs = 60 - currentTime.getSeconds();

    $('#countdown-days h1').text('0');
    $('#countdown-hours h1').text(countdownHours);
    $('#countdown-minutes h1').text(countdownMins);
    $('#countdown-seconds h1').text(countdownSecs);

}, 1000);
```

As you can tell it isn't ideal for what we need it for since it counts down to 7pm in the timezone you're in.

Any help/examples would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you in advance, Lixorp.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is being caused by clients having different time zones on their devices. If you want to avoid this you will need to send some time information down to the client from the server.

Step 1: (Server) Calculate how long until the timer should expire and send it to client

Step 2: (Client) Calculate how long until that time will occur based on users time zone.

Step 3. (Client) Start your timer based on the calculation in step 2.

For your client javascript (and server if you are using node.js) the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) library is great for doing date mathmatics in a simple way (see [durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/))

## Simple sudo example

client.js

```
// you could hardcode date or send it from server
var now = moment(),
   deadline = moment('12-25-2014', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
   secondsUntilDeadline = now.diff(deadline, 'seconds');
```

Comment: That seems quite complicated, I'm not too good with jscript. Also, in step two, wouldn't that give a different countdown time in different timezones since you're calculating how long that time is on the user's timezone? If so, that's basically the result I'm getting now, which isn't the desired result.

Comment: I have added a small example for you

Answer (score 0):

The best day to do this would be to do the countdown server-side and send the results to the client. You will have to use a server-side language such as PHP or Ruby. You can also use Javascript syntax server-side using Node.js.

Good Luck!